# How to pass Javascript as a string to function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to copy some Javascript code using a function. In which, it is triggered from `HTML` code.

It is not working because the double quotes which are present `script` tag closes the `onclick` attribute.

```js
        function copytext(data){
            var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
            tempInput.setAttribute('value',data);
            document.body.append(tempInput);
            tempInput.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            tempInput.remove();
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="copytext('<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>');" ></button>
```

Comment: `<button onclick='copytext("<script  src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js\"></script>");' ></button>`

Comment: @Seblor I see no eval here

Comment: why load script in function ??

Comment: @Dr.Strange Likely a button saying "Copy jQuery script tag to clip board to insert into your page"

Comment: @seblor Where is this script executed? I see a string copied to clipboard. Nothing else

Comment: I am sure there is a similar button with  `<button onclick='copytext("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css\"/>")'>Copy CSS</button>`

Comment: @mplungjan you are right. I got the wrong idea from what the title said, and read too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes were not escaped properly

```js
function copytext(data){
            console.log(data);
            var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
            tempInput.setAttribute('value',data);
            document.body.append(tempInput);
            tempInput.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            tempInput.remove();
        }
```

```html
 
<button onclick="copytext(`<script  src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>`);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes

```
<button onclick='copytext("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js\"></script>")'>Copy</button>
```

or in newer browsers use a template literal

```
<button onclick="copytext(`<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>`)">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function copytext(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var tempInput = document.createElement("input");
  tempInput.setAttribute('value', data);
  document.body.append(tempInput);
  tempInput.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  tempInput.remove();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copytext(`<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>`);">aaaa</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below is a possible, but as of yet untested solution

```
#< script id="scriptTagId" type=''... #>
document.scripts.namedItem("scriptTagId")
```